# Using Elasticsearch to collect information from Yahoo-Finance query server

Tags: python, elasticsearch, httprequest, large-data, yahoo-finance

I have been trying to query yahoo finance using the following url:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&query=A*&type=equity&count=10001&start=0&scroll=true

I receive this message:

{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"internal-error","description":"Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.]"}}}

I am not familiar with Elasticsearch so for the last few days I have been trying to learn about it and spent almost all my time trying to figure this out but I can't find much information about this.
I'd rather completely avoid using Elasticsearch and use python to write a request to that link and somehow set the "index.max_result_window" so the website would return more than 10,000 rows of data.
I am trying to save the data I receive from the above url as a json file.

I have tried to register for the free Elasticsearch service online but I could not figure out how to provide the above url as an input source.

any help is highly appreciated.

***------ UPDATE 12 Jan 2023 ------***

I could not find a way to resolve this specific problem but I managed to obtain the data by breaking down the query into smaller pieces.
For example, Query A would return more than 10,000 rows of data so I broke down A into a list of all possible alphabet combinations and conducted the query. This way, the results are less than 10,000 and then I concatenated all the results.

Comment: Please add your update as an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to retrieve more than 10,000 rows from Yahoo Finance but I found a workout around it.

I managed to obtain the data by breaking down the query into smaller pieces. For example, Query "A" would return more than 10,000 rows of data so I broke down "A" into a list of all possible alphabet combinations and conducted the query.
This way, the results are less than 10,000 and then I concatenated all the results.
Hope this can help others trying to retrieve a large set of data from Yahoo Finance

Answer (score 0):

This setting is set at index level, that is the elastic used by yahoo finance.  You cant make this change with query, only index managers can do.

Elastic search has scroll API which can be used for this elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: Thanks, I found the link you provided during my research and I am re-reading the document again to try to figure this out. But does this mean that there is a parameter I can set while sending my request to the Yahoo-Finance query server so it can return more than 10,000 rows of data or this is something hard-coded by yahoo finance and we can never retrieve more than 10,000 data points?

Comment: Something hard-coded by yahoo finance

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve more than 10,000 data points from this url?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Elasticsearch. Yahoo is using Elasticsearch. You're using Yahoo's API.

You'll have to do multiple API requests to Yahoo to retrieve more than 10,000 data points.

You can use the `start` query parameter to specify the index of the next data point that you would want to retrieve. So you would make API calls to, for example:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&query=A*&type=equity&count=10000&start=0&scroll=true
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&query=A*&type=equity&count=10000&start=1&scroll=true
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&query=A*&type=equity&count=10000&start=2&scroll=true
...
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. but when I use the second or third link that you provided I still get the following message: "{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"internal-error","description":"Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10002]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.]"}}}"

Comment: Have you found any documentation made available by Yahoo about this endpoint or where did you find out about it?

Comment: I found out about this through online search.